# How to conditionally load a different index.html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an angular app, and using a standard index.html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>    
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

What I'd like to do is have a different index.html or a "home.html" file loaded, if a user is not logged into the app.  The home.html will be a single static page marketing site with it's own design and css/js.  I'd like that page to be served from the '/' route, and other routes to be handled by the angular app.

How would I dynamically load a different starting html file?

Comment: use javascript location like this window.location = 'your page url';

Comment: You can use ng-include and different html file depends on you state(login or not) for example: `ng-if=logged ng-include="logged template"`

Comment: your question is a bit broad.  this "index" doesn't have any unique elements other than scripts, so it's not really necessary to replace this file.  If you want angular in control of the "home" content, then it should be a route in angular, and `home.html` should be a template loaded into the `ng-view`.  If you *don't* want angular to be in control of the content, then it should be a route on the server, that angular doesn't know about at all.

Comment: @Claises that is correct.  I'd like to have a "home.html" file (with it's own css/js) that has nothing to do with Angular.  It's just a static file.  How would I just serve that if the user visits '/'?

Answer (score 1):

The logic to route to another html should be placed in your login module. It could be not related with Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

There are some code to redirect another page from outside or inside of angular app

```
$location.url('/RouteTo/index');

$location.url('/index');

$window.location.href="http://www.domain.com/home";

window.location = "http://www.domain.com/home";
```

you can get your host for app `$window.location.host`